# Interpret Lomb Scargle periodogram

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, astropy

lomb scargle periodogram:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal
from astropy.time import Time
from astropy.timeseries import LombScargle

m5_data = pd.read_csv('tmp')
m5_data.head()

     date    sales
0  2011-01-29  32631.0
1  2011-01-30  31749.0
2  2011-01-31  23783.0
3  2011-02-01  25412.0
4  2011-02-02  19146.0

"""Converting dates to MJD """
tmp_str = m5_data.iloc[:,0].astype(pd.StringDtype())
t_date = np.array(tmp_str.values,dtype = 'str')
t_date = Time(t_date, format='isot', scale='utc')
t_date.format = 'mjd'

y = m5_data.iloc[:,1]
m5_ls = LombScargle(t_date, y)
m5_frequency, m5_power = m5_ls.autopower()
plt.plot(m5_frequency,m5_power)
plt.show()
```

1. What does the x axis represent? Is it frequencies in days or is it            frequencies in 1/day?
2. So the spike at 2 does that mean there is a period of every two days or does it mean there is a period 1/2 days, which is a fractional day and I do not understand how I could get fractional days when I only have 1 observation per day.

The overall goal is to find if the data is periodic. Given this data is sales of a product from a store I would expect that if the data is periodic that the periods would be 7days(weekly), 30days(monthly), 182days(semi annually)

So the spike at 2 does not make sense to me.

Comment: The example plot in [the documentation](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/timeseries/lombscargle.html) is labelled as "...periodogram shows a clear spike at a frequency of 1 cycle per unit time...". Based on that, one might assume that your x axis is "cycles per day" since your units are days

Comment: The [**Note**](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/timeseries/lombscargle.html#basic-usage) on that page writes: *All frequencies in LombScargle are not angular frequencies, but rather frequencies of oscillation **(i.e., number of cycles per unit time)**.*

Comment: answer is [here](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/41194/interpret-lomb-scargle-periodogram)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it not specifically a programming question and already has an answer on astronomy.stackexchange